# How to make web part static content searchable?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, web-part, visual-web-part

I have a local, on-premise dev installation of SharePoint 2013 standard edition.

I created a visual web part with sample static content. Added this webpart to a webpart page. When I do a search from site search box, I do not get any result for the terms mentioned in the web part's static content. I can see that `Local SharePoint site` content source is set to `continuous crawl` but still I dont see the search results.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

If the static content is placed inside the markup of the .ascx control, it won't appear in the search results as the .ascx control reside in physical folder. If you add the static content directly on the page either in content editor webpart or some page field, it will show in search results as the data now is stored in content database.

Answer (score 0):

First of all look at the crawl logs to confirm the page where you put the web part has been crawled by the search engine. If it is, and you still cannot find the page, ensure you have configured crawl to index content inside web parts.

- On the site, click Settings > Site Settings.
- Under Search, click
  Search and offline availability.
- In the Indexing ASPX Page Content
  section, There are following 3 option and you have to select "Always
  index all Web Parts on this site" option.

**Do not index Web Parts if this site contains fine-grained permissions**: When permissions of the ASPX page are different from the parent site, no content on the site appears in search results.

**Always index all Web Parts on this site**: Show content of all ASPX pages on the site in search results regardless of permissions.

**Never index any Web Parts on this site**: Hide content of all ASPX pages on the site from search results regardless of permissions.

[Source](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-content-on-a-site-to-be-searchable-2a420d01-4706-4d23-980e-c4c877113670)